# Draw an ASCII cuboid

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, geometry

Given three integers >= 2, create an ASCII cube in an orthogonal (cabinet) projection. 
The three integers represent height, width and depth (measured in visible characters) including the corners. The corners should be 'o's or '+', free choice.

w: 10, h: 5, d: 4 
Thus gives:

```
   o--------o
  /        /|
 /        / |
o--------o  |
|        |  o
|        | /
|        |/
o--------o
```

Now, to make this slightly harder, all faces can either be solid, transparent or missing.
We order the faces like this:

```
   o--------o
  /        /|
 /    2   / |
o--------o 3|
|        |  o
|   1    | /
|        |/
o--------o

  ---
  |2|
-------
|5|1|3|
-------
  |4|
  ---
  |6|
  ---
```

And supply a list of tokens, S, T or M. The original example is thus:

```
w 10
h 5
d 4
S S S S S S

   o--------o
  /        /|
 /        / |
o--------o  |
|        |  o
|        | /
|        |/ 
o--------o
```

If one face is transparent, we can see anything that is behind it:

```
T S S S S S

   o--------o
  /        /|
 /        / |
o--------o  |
|  o-----|  o
| /      | /
|/       |/
o--------o


T T T T T T

   o--------o
  /|       /|
 / |      / |
o--------o  |
|  o-----|--o
| /      | /
|/       |/
o--------o
```

For pairs of missing faces, adjacent edges or corners are no longer visible:

```
M M S S S S

   o--------o
  /|       /|
 / |      / |
o  |     o  |
|  o-----|  o
| /      | /
|/       |/
o--------o

M M S S M S

   o--------o
   |       /|
   |      / |
   |     o  |
   o-----|  o
  /      | /
 /       |/
o--------o
```

Code golf, shortest code wins!
Trailing spaces and newlines are fine, you're free to choose input method and input order.

Comment: How strict is your input format? can I make a function with 9 parameters?

Comment: @LiefdeWen `you're free to choose input method and input order`. And as nothing says otherwise, any of [the default input/output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?answertab=votes#tab-top) can be used.

Comment: Can I take an integer as bitmap for the transparent/solid flags?

Comment: @Titus Well.. alright. I guess it's a bit more entertaining if you actually can test the values by your self.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>190</s> 181 bytes

```
ＮωＡ⁻ω²ςＮηＡ⁻η²γＮδＡ⁻δ²χＡ⪪Ｓ αＦ›⊟αMＦ⟦ςγςγ⟧«oκ↶»Ｆ∧›⊟αM²«oς↷³oχ↷¹»Ｆ∧›⊟αM²«↷³oχ↷³oγ↶»Ｍ⁻ωδ⁻δηＦ⁼§α²SＧ↗δ↓η↙δ↑η Ｆ∧›⊟αM²«↶¹oχ↷³oγ↷»Ｆ⁼§α¹SＧ↗δ←ω↙δ→ω Ｆ∧›⊟αM²«↶¹oχ↶³oς»Ｆ⁼§α⁰SＵＯ±ωη ↷Ｆ›⊟αMＦ⟦γςγς⟧«oκ↷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVNNT4NAED3Lr9hwGpI2KX5c6qmJxtRIbcSeGg9boAuR7iIsoDH@dhx2sVjaWptoNpnszrx9M28m44U09QSNq2rMk1xO8tUiSKG0Lo1RlkWMgxPxPIOyR06tHinQ/x0XdnGhxrEOzu/ifI3zWr@bxJEE9cmVacQZYNwkJlqKqKVICdykAZVINxUJ0DrsmJZFVGheYFYsEO2TRd6NkylySDCFiZ@bx7O6RoWQd8FSAr4@NO@I@zu56yL3kRVrsoeIhRLO2tAGzuvg7GPSHk@/D8d2aL/NV0k7Xx/zrocTWl89v37JaZzBSI65H7wC1YMz3brzUxG/McFhOEtUdiTpkeGVKDkyNLc6nfbPEuWtZ3qMflWv/WfyNa4dwrY@@4A@rajc0tdAyn@TqGD7FBY/SRqsJd0vYoG7NQkY1oR73o5kszsH961ZNrS/2Le26VVlD4wL49xwiEMe8bjErfpF1c/iTw) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 9 bytes by optimising my conditions. Charcoal has no `else` token, so `if` commands always have two alternatives, unless they're at the end of a block or program. To avoid this, I use `for (<bool>)` instead of `if (<bool>)` which has a similar effect when the expression can only have the values 0 or 1 but saves a byte. (In order to achieve this I had to change the expressions so that they were always true when the body needed to be executed.) I was also able to optimise `if (<bool>) for (<int>)` into `for (And(bool, int))`.

Comment: Holy Christ O_O. I couldn't even figure out how to draw the cube itself using charcoal. Can you put up an example to draw a simple cube on the github examples folder? One that's been optimized? I want to compare my like... 50 byte answer to what it should've been.

Comment: @carusocomputing Sorry, I'm unclear as to what you mean by "simple cube", and I'm not an author of Charcoal itself, so I can't add an example.

Comment: You aren't?! Holy crap, who is? I honestly thought you were. Also, I'd ask to be a charcoal contributor. You could easily become one on github :). You're talented in the language, obviously. And by "simple cube" I mean the first half of the challenge, just making an `X * Y * Z `ASCII cube.

Comment: @carusocomputing ASCII-only is the main contributor as far as I can tell, although the esolang wiki does credit a second contributor.

Comment: at the very least I'd contact them with a few of your examples, you've taken it further than anyone else I've seen. I'd love to get more explanations of your code, I've followed your Charcoal answers for a bit now because the language is interesting to me.

Comment: @carusocomputing 50 bytes? Not bad! My first attempt was 56 bytes, but I was eventually able to pare it down to 29: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBI7pKRyFDR6FcR6FQRwGZXY7KLoeridVUqObiDMgsyy/xSU0r0TDUtObizExT0MgES3AGFGXmlWgo5SuBxKE858TiEqA8SKSWq/b/f0MDLlMuk/@6Zf91i3MA "Charcoal – Try It Online")

Comment: @Neil I can give you edit permissions to Charcoal if you want

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>318</s> <s>314</s> 308 bytes

Takes width, height and depth as integers and the faces as an array of characters.

```js
(w,h,d,l,M=(n,F)=>[...Array(n+1).keys()].map(F),a=M((L=w--+d)*(h--+--d),i=>++i%L?' ':`
`),D=(t,Y=0,X=d,W=t&1?d:w,H=t&2?d:h,F=l[t>>2])=>F>'R'&&M(W,i=>M(H,j=>a[p=L*(Y+j-i*(t&1))+X+i-(t&2?j:0)]=(x=!(i&&i-W)|2*!(j&&j-H))?' |-o|/o/-o'[t%4*3+x]:a[F>'S'?p:0])))=>D(20)&D(D(14,h)&D(17,d,0),d,D(9,d,w)&D(6))||a.join``
```

#### How?

The function ***M()*** processes a given callback ***F*** on a given range ***[0...n]***.

```js
M = (n, F) => [...Array(n + 1).keys()].map(F)
```

The variable ***a*** holds a flat array representing a grid of size ***(w+d) x (h+d-1)***. It is initially filled with rows of spaces terminated with newlines.

```js
a = M((L = w-- + d) * (h-- + --d), i => ++i % L ? ' ' : '\n')
```

The function ***D()*** is used to 'draw' a face of the cuboid.

The two least significant bits of the parameter ***t*** hold the face type:

- 0 = rear / front
- 1 = left / right
- 2 = bottom / top

Bits #2 to #4 hold the 0-based face index.

```js
D = (                                           // given:
  t, Y = 0, X = d,                              // - the type and the initial coordinates
  W = t & 1 ? d : w,                            // - the drawing width
  H = t & 2 ? d : h,                            // - the drawing height
  F = l[t >> 2]                                 // - the character representing the status
) =>                                            //
  F > 'R' &&                                    // provided that the face is not missing:
  M(W, i =>                                     // for each i in [0...W]:
    M(H, j =>                                   //  for each j in [0...H]:
      a[                                        //    update the output
        p = L * (Y + j - i * (t & 1)) +         //    at position p
            X + i - (t & 2 ? j : 0)             //
      ] =                                       //    with either:
      (x = !(i && i - W) | 2 * !(j && j - H)) ? //    - '|', '-' or '/' on edges
        ' |-o|/o/-o'[t % 4 * 3 + x]             //    - or 'o' on vertices
      :                                         //
        a[F > 'S' ? p : 0]                      //    - or a space on solid faces
    )                                           //    - or the current character on
  )                                             //      transparent faces
```

Faces are drawn in the following order:

```js
D(5 * 4 + 0, 0, d)  // face #5 (rear)
D(3 * 4 + 2, h, d)  // face #3 (bottom)
D(4 * 4 + 1, d, 0)  // face #4 (left)
D(2 * 4 + 1, d, w)  // face #2 (right)
D(1 * 4 + 2, 0, d)  // face #1 (top)
D(0 * 4 + 0, d, 0)  // face #0 (front)
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

(w,h,d,l,M=(n,F)=>[...Array(n+1).keys()].map(F),a=M((L=w--+d)*(h--+--d),i=>++i%L?' ':`
`),D=(t,Y=0,X=d,W=t&1?d:w,H=t&2?d:h,F=l[t>>2])=>F>'R'&&M(W,i=>M(H,j=>a[p=L*(Y+j-i*(t&1))+X+i-(t&2?j:0)]=(x=!(i&&i-W)|2*!(j&&j-H))?' |-o|/o/-o'[t%4*3+x]:a[F>'S'?p:0])))=>D(20)&D(D(14,h)&D(17,d,0),d,D(9,d,w)&D(6))||a.join``

let update = _ => O.innerHTML = f(W.value, H.value, D.value, [...F.value])
update()
```

```html
<label>Width <input id="W" size="3" value="10" oninput="update()" /></label>
<label>Height <input id="H" size="3" value="5" oninput="update()" /></label>
<label>Depth <input id="D" size="3" value="4" oninput="update()" /></label>
<label>Faces <input id="F" size="6" value="MMSSMS" oninput="update()" /></label>
<pre id="O"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.11](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/tree/3390e7e2907aa87f2ebfaa0f46f3665cc32728a0), <s>200</s> <s>194</s> <s>193</s> <s>192</s> 190 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
b³@*⁶
ž}1}X⁵
;aκ⁴
2-³
* o1Ο²
d=?a³:?∫:¹
be.Aā6∫D,ζLI%:C?abe"DCa∫:c+H⁴d+ /ž}{"a+Hy"e³┐²čž|"b³┌²žz"EBAøp”,ōkB°s9θW=*↑(⅜⅞~υ=\⁰ōwūΧ►ΣΤP░¶Ο⁽◄Φ7⅟▲s#‘┌Θdwι+#¶ŗ!!6c=?6d=?2aI⁶e³∙ž}5¹b+⁴Ie³@∙⁵}4¹2+⁴⁶⁵
```

Takes input in the order

```
width
height
depth
down-face
left-face
back-face
top-face
right-face
front-face
```

Tied!
[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=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__,inputs=MTAlMEE1JTBBNCUwQVQlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjBkb3duLWZhY2UlMjAlMjAlMjAldTIxOTYlMEFUJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwbGVmdC1mYWNlJTIwJTIwJTIwJTVFVyUyMCUyMCUwQVQlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjBiYWNrLWZhY2UlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjBIJTBBVCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMHRvcC1mYWNlJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwRCUwQVQlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjByaWdodC1mYWNlJTBBUyUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMGZyb250LWZhY2U_) (compressed value changed to be V0.12 compatible)